# How do I generate a random permutation of a (long [millions-length]) list of symbols?

Tags: random, combinatorics, inequalities, permutation

I have a list of length twelve:

```
p = {t[1, 1], t[1, 2], t[1, 3], t[1, 4], t[2, 2], t[2, 3], t[2, 4], 
 t[1, 5], t[3, 3], t[3, 4], t[1, 6], t[4, 4]}
```

and a set of inequalities

```
U = t[1, 1] > 0 && -t[1, 2]^2 + t[1, 1] t[2, 2] > 
  0 && -t[1, 3]^2 t[2, 2] + 2 t[1, 2] t[1, 3] t[2, 3] - 
   t[1, 1] t[2, 3]^2 - t[1, 2]^2 t[3, 3] + t[1, 1] t[2, 2] t[3, 3] > 
  0 && t[1, 4]^2 t[2, 3]^2 - 2 t[1, 3] t[1, 4] t[2, 3] t[2, 4] + 
   t[1, 3]^2 t[2, 4]^2 - t[1, 4]^2 t[2, 2] t[3, 3] + 
   2 t[1, 2] t[1, 4] t[2, 4] t[3, 3] - t[1, 1] t[2, 4]^2 t[3, 3] + 
   2 t[1, 3] t[1, 4] t[2, 2] t[3, 4] - 
   2 t[1, 2] t[1, 4] t[2, 3] t[3, 4] - 
   2 t[1, 2] t[1, 3] t[2, 4] t[3, 4] + 
   2 t[1, 1] t[2, 3] t[2, 4] t[3, 4] + t[1, 2]^2 t[3, 4]^2 - 
   t[1, 1] t[2, 2] t[3, 4]^2 - t[1, 3]^2 t[2, 2] t[4, 4] + 
   2 t[1, 2] t[1, 3] t[2, 3] t[4, 4] - t[1, 1] t[2, 3]^2 t[4, 4] - 
   t[1, 2]^2 t[3, 3] t[4, 4] + t[1, 1] t[2, 2] t[3, 3] t[4, 4] > 0
```

involving the members of the list.

I--undoubtedly foolhardily (because of the computational demands involved)--want to try repeatedly invoking the command

```
GenericCylindricalDecomposition[U, q],
```

where `q` is a random permutation (one of the 12!=479,001,600 possible) of the members of `p` (to find which--if successful, for further integration purposes--has the lowest `LeafCount`).

The immediate question at hand, though, is how I can generate such a random permutation `q` without having to explicitly create such an immensely long list from which to randomly choose members.

Comment: I am not sure whether I fully understand the question, but are you perhaps looking for ``q = RandomSample[p]``?

Comment: RandomSample[p] accomplishes what I sought. Thanks, Domen!